# Does decimal fraction has hex value?/can hex be fraction?

Tags: number-theory, binary, decimal-expansion

I was wondering if a decimal fraction could be converted into a hexadecimal

fraction? I have seen it many times ? but I have been also told that decimal or

binary fraction has no meaning in hex. If there is , I would appreciate if someone

shows me the best way of converting a decimal fraction into a hexadecimal fraction.

Thanks.

Comment: Terminology question:  What do we call a base-16 fractional number like $A6F2.B76D$

Answer (score 0):

If you have a decimal fraction, simply convert the numerator and denominator to hex, and you've won:

$$\left(\frac{42}{128}\right)_{10} = \left(\frac{2\text{A}}{80}\right)_{16}$$

Converting from hex to binary is even easier, because each hex digit maps to a four-digit binary number:

$$\left(\frac{2\text{A}}{80}\right)_{16} = \left(\frac{\text{0010 1010}}{\text{1000 0000}}\right)_{2}$$